# Django Oscar: Nothing showing up at URL "http://localhost:8000/buy/"

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-oscar

I wanted to include an ecommerce portal on my website and I have done everything as given on the "Create your Shop page" as given in **Django-Oscar** documentation, just that in 
**urls.py** instead of

```
url(r'', include(application.urls)),
```

I have added

```
url(r'^buy/', include(application.urls)),
```

but the problem is that when I hit the url it is neither showing anything nor giving an error.

Any idea what could be the problem?

It could be some urls are clashing or something else trivial but I am not able to understand from where to start debugging.

File **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from view import AboutusView, TwentySevenView
import apps.users.views
from django.conf import settings

    #oscar urls
    from oscar.app import application

    admin.site.site_header = ''
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
                           # Examples:
                           # url(r'^$', 'torquehp.views.home', name='home'),
                           # url(r'^users/', include('users.urls')),
                           url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
                           url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                           url(r'^about-us/$', AboutusView.as_view(), name="about-us"),
                           url(r'^24x7/$', TwentySevenView.as_view(), name="24x7"),
                           url(r'^$', apps.users.views.user_home, name="home"),
                           url(r'^markdown/', include('django_markdown.urls')),
                           url(r'^users/', include('apps.users.urls')),
                           url(r'^doorstep/', include('apps.doorstep.urls')),
                           url(r'^cars/', include('apps.cars.urls')),
                           url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
                           # urls for zinnia
                           url(r'^blog/', include('zinnia.urls', namespace='zinnia')),
                           url(r'^comments/', include('django_comments.urls')),
                           url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                               {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, }),
                           # oscar URLs
                           url(r'^buy/', include(application.urls)),
    )
```

File **settings.py**

```
import os
import sys
from oscar import get_core_apps
from oscar import OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR
from oscar.defaults import *

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
location = lambda x: os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), x)

# sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps'))  # to store apps in apps/ directory


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'apps.users',
    'apps.doorstep',
    'apps.cars',
    'django_markdown',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django_comments', 
    'mptt',             
    'tagging',          
    'zinnia',           
    'compressor',
    ] + get_core_apps()
# specifying the comments app
# COMMENTS_APP = 'zinnia_threaded_comments'

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'oscar.apps.basket.middleware.BasketMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
)

# Authentication backend used by python-social-auth
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends.EmailBackend',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends",
    "social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect",
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "zinnia.context_processors.version",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
    'oscar.apps.promotions.context_processors.promotions',
    'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
    'oscar.apps.customer.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
    'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata'
)

# TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
#     'app_namespace.Loader',
# )

ROOT_URLCONF = 'torquehp.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'torquehp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': "",
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}

# Internationalization

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOGIN_URL = '/users/login/'

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates').replace('\\', '/'),
    location('templates'),
    OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR,
)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),


)
REGISTRATION_INVALID = 50
MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    REGISTRATION_INVALID: 'InvalidDetails',
}
# temporary , should not be in settings file
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = ""
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = ""
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = ""
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = ""

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/blog/'

# ------------------------------------ #
# Settings for sending email #

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
# ------------------------------------ #


# site id for django sites framework
SITE_ID = 1

# configuration settings for  django-zinnia
ZINNIA_PING_EXTERNAL_URLS = False
ZINNIA_SAVE_PING_DIRECTORIES = False
ZINNIA_MARKUP_LANGUAGE = 'markdown'
ZINNIA_UPLOAD_TO = 'uploads/zinnia/'
# TimeZone Settings
USE_TZ = True

# ------------------------ #
# django s=oscar search settings
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.simple_backend.SimpleEngine',
    },
}
```

Screenshots:

**http://localhost:8000/buy/**
[image]

**http://localhost:8000/buy/catalogue/**

[image]

Comment: do you have an `application/urls.py` file? Is `application` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting? Is there an `application/__init__.py` file?

Comment: @Ewan django-oscar makes you import "from oscar.app import application"

Comment: My apologies; I have just seen the tag. And if you go to `buy/offers/`? still nothing? or a 404? do you have `DEBUG=True` in your settings as well?

Comment: @Ewan yes Debug = True is set , and I tried with /buy/catalogue/ and it is giving the following in plain text.

0 results.
No products found.

Means its working but there is some problem with templates or something.

Comment: And it shows products if you just remove your `^buy/` from the `urls.py`?

Comment: @Ewan No I have something else set as default url(r'^$') page but I have tried with default URL and and placing it above my homepage URL so it gets cached first but still it is giving a blank page.

Comment: @PrinceArora I have try to follow the guide at https://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/releases-1.0/internals/getting_started.html and I didn't encounter any problem. I managed to change the url to `/buy/` prefix without any issue. Perhaps you need to share your project code.

Comment: @PrinceArora or at least please share your project `urls.py` file. Also note the order is important in where the urlpatterns is defined.

Comment: @Ewan Updated the question,sorry for delay

Comment: @Yeo updated the question,sorry for delay

Comment: I think you need to post more code. Like your project directory structure. It's possible your templates/static files are broken but it's hard to say.

Comment: @PrinceArora, can you share the entire project or partial project code whichever relevant? this is very strange and shouldn't happened if you follow the django-oscar tutorial from fresh.

Comment: @Yeo posted settings.py.

Comment: @onyeka posted settings.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that in your second screenshot `localhost:8000/buy/catalogue/` you actually get a result. It would seem as if you haven't defined your own templates or somehow need to fix your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` or `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` settings.

I haven't used oscar, but that fact that you get something on screen seems like a template loading issue to me.

[See their docs about setting the template_context_processors](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/internals/getting_started.html#django-settings)

Can you post your settings please?

Update:

After seeing your settings, the template_context_processors look correct. I next looked at oscar's templates and they seem to extend without qualifying the oscar directory. For example, layout.html (/oscar/templates/oscar/layout.html) does this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

Now, if you also have a 'base.html' file in your own project directory, say project_dir/templates/base.html, then it'll probably use that instead. Can you try to temporarily rename that file (if it exists) and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

urls.py

```
url(r'^buy/', include("app.urls")),
```

Then under your app directory create a file called `urls.py`

`app/urls.py`

```
# this is your “http://localhost:8000/buy/”
url(r'^$', ViewName.as_view(), name="thename"),
```

Comment: It is not my app, It in Django-Oscar's app so I think it is coded fine.

Answer (score 0):

In app/urls.py add the following line:

```
url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
```

This will redirect you to the index function in app/views.py
In app/views.py do something like that:

```
def index(request):
  #Your logic here
  return render(request,'urpoll/index.html'{'category':categorys,'ques':ques,'url':url})
```

This will render index.html with categories,ques,url. In index.HTML so something like that:

```
{{ if category }}
{{ category }}
{{ endif }}
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a naming collision with templates. Django's default template loader, which I assume you're using, can be a bit unintuitive.  When you ask it for a template with a given name, it goes through your `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple in settings in order, checking in each one for a templates folder. If there are two templates with the same path in two different apps, it will always take the first one it finds.

That's why the recommendation in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something) is to 'namespace' your templates by keeping them all in another folder with the name of your app, within the templates folder. Oscar does this, so their templates are in `oscar/templates/oscar`, so they shouldn't be colliding with any other apps, but I'm wondering if maybe you put an 'oscar' folder within the templates of one of your apps, possibly clashing with `base.html`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that django-oscar is not meant to be included under a sub-path, such as `/buy/`. In their documentation, their example shows installing it as:

```
url(r'', include(application.urls)),
```

If you look at [the source](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/app.py#L27) of `get_urls()`, which provides the return value for `application.urls`, you can see that it does not provide a urlpattern to match `r'^$'`, which is what you would need to match at the URL you are trying to view.

In short, you should follow exactly what the documentation recommends, or you will get unexpected results.

Comment: I have tried the same with only vanilla django-oscar installation and it was working fine.